# Disable Copy in CCP context menu for JsTree

Tags: jstree

How can I disable the "Copy" (but not cut / paste) functionality of the jsTree right click context menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pretty much did the trick.

```
 $("#housingTree").jstree({
            "plugins": ["themes", "html_data", "ui", "crrm", "hotkeys", "contextmenu"],

            "core": { "initially_open": ["phtml_1"] },


            "contextmenu": {
                "items": function ($node) {

                    return {
                        "Rename": {
                            "label": "Rename",
                            "action": function (obj) { this.rename(obj); }
                        },
                        "Create": {
                            "label": "Create",
                            "action": function (obj) { this.create(obj); }
                        },
                        "Delete": {
                            "label": "Delete",
                            "action": function (obj) { this.remove(obj); }
                        },
                        "Cut": {
                            "label": "Cut",
                            "action": function (obj) { this.cut(obj); }
                        },
                        "Paste": {
                            "label": "Paste",
                            "action": function (obj) { this.paste(obj); }
                        }
                    };
                }
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

i dont know if the action functions are the default functions or custom functions, but that didnt work for me... anyway your post did set me in the right path! thanks!

this is how i did it, after finding another post:

```
"contextmenu": {
        "items": function ($node) {
            var tree = $("#html1Tree").jstree(true);
            return {
                "Rename": {
                    "label": "Rename",
                    "action": function (obj) { 
                        tree.edit($node);
                    }
                },
                "Create": {
                    "label": "Create",
                    "action": function (obj) { 
                        $node = tree.create_node($node);
                        tree.edit($node); 
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

[jsTree and Context Menu: modify items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21096141/jstree-and-context-menu-modify-items)

Answer (score 1):

The shorter approach could be

```
"contextmenu": {
   "items": function(node) {
           var defaultItems = $.jstree.defaults.contextmenu.items();
           console.log("default items : "+JSON.stringify(defaultItems));
          delete defaultItems.ccp.submenu.copy;
           return defaultItems;
        }
    },
```

You can console.log(defaultItems). It wil print json representation of object. You can modify other properties also.

Answer (score 0):

this is my easiest option.
All main code placed in "contextmenu.items" block.

```
$('#c-list').jstree({
        "core": {
            "themes": {"responsive": false},
            "check_callback": true,
        },
        "types": {
            "default": {
                "icon": "fa fa-folder text-warning fa-lg"
            },
            "file": {
                "icon": "fa fa-file text-warning fa-lg"
            }
        },
        "contextmenu":{
            'items' : function(node) {
                var items = $.jstree.defaults.contextmenu.items();
                items.ccp = false;

                return items;
            }
        },
        "plugins": ["contextmenu", "dnd", "types", "search", "wholerow","checkbox"]
    });
```