# Overriding jstree context menu in v3.3.5

Tags: javascript, jstree

The `contextmenu` plugin of the `jstree` has evolved substantially in syntax, apparently undergoing several breaking changes. Version 3.3.5 was released on January 2, 2018. As best I can tell, none of the implementations for custom menu items [posted in a previous SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21096141/jstree-and-context-menu-modify-items/32329493#32329493) are working in v3.3.5.

What is the correct syntax for removing one menu item (`create`) and adding a new one in its place?

EDIT: Greg Hmhmm's solution does technically function, and for that I am grateful. However, it lacks cut/copy/paste functionality, requires re-implementation of everything, and is rather opaque, making it difficult to build upon. The other examples are simpler, but, alas, do not seem to work.